# How to get Google Sheets to ignore quotation marks inside a formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a formula in Google Sheets that will take a HTML tag as text, and lookup a value in another cell to add a unique URL to it.

For example:

```
<img class="test-tmn-pxl" data-src="[impression_url_here]" width="1" height="1" style="display:block;margin-bottom:-1px;" />
```

where `impression_url_here` is replaced with a URL from cell A1 (as an example).

However, because everything else apart from `impression_url_here` will stay exactly the same, when I try to add it to my formula as text it's just picking up the first set of qutation marks and closing the text portion of the formula early.

Here's what I have so far:

```
="<img class="test-tmn-pxl" data-src="["&=A1&"]" width="1" height="1" style="display:block;margin-bottom:-1px;" />""
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first double quote in your formula indicates the start of the text, and the next double quote indicates the end of it, even if you put it in the middle of your text. As far as Google sheet is concerned, your text ended at the second double quote. If you want to pack some HTML string values within the final output of the cell, use single quotes to differentiate them.

```
="<img class='test-tmn-pxl' data-src='[" & A1 & "]' width='1' height='1' style='display:block;margin-bottom:-1px;' />"
```

I don't get what the square brackets are there for, but I'll leave it to you.

[Update]

If you do want to use double quotes for your HTML strings as well, the escape character in Google sheets is, [sigh], double quote. So if you want to output `"` without breaking the string, your formula should say `""`.

Here's the full suggested formula:

```
="<img class=""test-tmn-pxl"" data-src=""[" & A1 & "]"" width=""1"" height=""1"" style=""display:block;margin-bottom:-1px;"" />"
```

Comment: This sort of works, but I need the quotation marks inside the text portion to be double quotes not single, this is the issue - it's not about me using single quotation marks to differentiate them for me, it's that the HTML tag is specifically looking for those double quotation marks. Does that make sense?

I guess i'm more looking for a character or something I can place in front of the quotation marks I want Google Sheets to ignore? Is that a thing?

Comment: Well, yeah, Google sheets does offer a way to escape double quotes, but it would make your formula look much weirder. The character that escapes a double quote is, double quote. So `""` outputs `"` without breaking the string. I'll update my answer with the full formula.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm after - I agree it looks very weird, but is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula, this make the text same as it looks in the google sheet preview.

```
clean(A1)
```

where the Parameter A1 is the content that you want to clean.